# how to use nested loops for iterating two arrays in Python?

Tags: arrays, nested

How do you best re-write this code in order to have the same output? Possibly with one or more nested loops.

```
months =["January","February","March","April"]
days_in_month =[32,29,32,31]

jan = months[0]
feb = months[1]
mar = months[2]
apr = months[3]

days_in_jan = days_in_month[0]
days_in_feb = days_in_month[1]
days_in_mar = days_in_month[2]
days_in_apr = days_in_month[3]

for day in range(1,days_in_jan):
    print(jan,day)
for day in range(1,days_in_feb):
    print(feb,day)      
for day in range(1,days_in_mar):
    print(mar,day)
for day in range(1,days_in_apr):
    print(apr,day)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two loops with `enumerate` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)) :

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
days_in_month = [32, 29, 32, 31]

for number_month, month in enumerate(months):
    for one_day in range(1, days_in_month[number_month]):
      print(month, one_day)
```

Another method, if the two lists are of the same length:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
days_in_month = [32, 29, 32, 31]

for i in range(len(months)):
    for one_day in range(1, days_in_month[i]):
      print(months[i], one_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could convert months and days into a dictionary key-value pair:

```
months = ["January","February","March","April"]
days_in_months = [32,29,32,31]
month_dict = dict(zip(months,days_in_months))
```

Then, you can get the same result with a nested for loop:

```
for month in month_dict: 
    for day in range(1,month_dict[month]): 
        print(month,day)
```

Comment: make sure you close the post by marking the best answer!